# How do I specify a schema when loading a csv from S3 in Spark with Scala?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I've googled through multiple syntax iterations on stack, and none of them are working for me.  My code is as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, DoubleType};

val schema1 = (new StructType)
    .add("PASSENGERID", IntegerType, true)
    .add("PCLASS", IntegerType, true)
    .add("NAME", IntegerType, true)
    .add("SEX", StringType, true)
    .add("AGE", DoubleType, true)
    .add("SIBSP", IntegerType, true)
    .add("PARCH", IntegerType, true)
    .add("TICKET", StringType, true)
    .add("FARE", DoubleType, true)
    .add("CABIN", StringType, true)
    .add("EMBARKED", StringType, true)

 val schema2 = StructType(
    StructField("PASSENGERID", IntegerType, true) ::
    StructField("PCLASS", IntegerType, true) ::
    StructField("NAME", IntegerType, true) ::
    StructField("SEX", StringType, true) ::
    StructField("AGE", DoubleType, true) ::
    StructField("SIBSP", IntegerType, true) ::
    StructField("PARCH", IntegerType, true) ::
    StructField("TICKET", StringType, true) ::
    StructField("FARE", DoubleType, true) ::
    StructField("CABIN", StringType, true) ::
    StructField("EMBARKED", StringType, true) :: Nil)

val schema3 = StructType(Array(
    StructField("PASSENGERID", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("PCLASS", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("NAME", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("SEX", StringType, true),
    StructField("AGE", DoubleType, true),
    StructField("SIBSP", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("PARCH", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("TICKET", StringType, true),
    StructField("FARE", DoubleType, true),
    StructField("CABIN", StringType, true),
    StructField("EMBARKED", StringType, true)))

val schema4 = StructType(Seq(
    StructField("PASSENGERID", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("PCLASS", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("NAME", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("SEX", StringType, true),
    StructField("AGE", DoubleType, true),
    StructField("SIBSP", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("PARCH", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("TICKET", StringType, true),
    StructField("FARE", DoubleType, true),
    StructField("CABIN", StringType, true),
    StructField("EMBARKED", StringType, true)
))

val schema5 = StructType(
  List(
    StructField("PASSENGERID", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("PCLASS", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("NAME", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("SEX", StringType, true),
    StructField("AGE", DoubleType, true),
    StructField("SIBSP", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("PARCH", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("TICKET", StringType, true),
    StructField("FARE", DoubleType, true),
    StructField("CABIN", StringType, true),
    StructField("EMBARKED", StringType, true)
  )
)

/*
val df = spark.read
    .option("header", true)
    .csv("s3a://mybucket/ybspark/input/PASSENGERS.csv")
    .schema(schema)
*/

//this works
val df = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("s3a://mybucket/ybspark/input/PASSENGERS.csv")

df.show(false)
df.printSchema()

//fun errors
val df1 = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("s3a://mybucket/ybspark/input/PASSENGERS.csv").schema(schema1)
val df2 = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("s3a://mybucket/ybspark/input/PASSENGERS.csv").schema(schema2)
val df3 = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("s3a://mybucket/ybspark/input/PASSENGERS.csv").schema(schema3)
val df4 = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("s3a://mybucket/ybspark/input/PASSENGERS.csv").schema(schema4)
val df5 = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("s3a://mybucket/ybspark/input/PASSENGERS.csv").schema(schema5)
```

The data is the kaggle titanic survival set, with fields in the header capitalized.  I've tried this as a script submit to spark-shell as well as run commands within spark-shell manually.  The spark-shell -i spits out some syntax errors on the dfX reads, if I manually load any of the schemas they seem fine though, and the reads all have the same error.

```
scala> val df4 = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("s3a://mybucket/ybspark/input/PASSENGERS.csv").schema(schema4)
<console>:26: error: overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
  (fieldIndex: Int)org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField <and>
  (names: Set[String])org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType <and>
  (name: String)org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType)
       val df4 = spark.read.option("header", true).csv("s3a://mybucket/ybspark/input/PASSENGERS.csv").schema(schema4)
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.  I'm on Spark version 2.4.4 on AWS EMR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `inferSchema` param `false` so that spark will not inferSchema while loading data.

Move your `.schema` before `.csv` as DataFrame object will not have `schema` function.

Please check below code.

```
scala> val df1 = spark.read.option("header", true).option("inferSchema", false).schema(schema1).csv("s3a://mybucket/ybspark/input/PASSENGERS\.csv")
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [PASSENGERID: int, PCLASS: int ... 9 more fields]

scala> val df2 = spark.read.option("header", true).option("inferSchema", false).schema(schema2).csv("s3a://mybucket/ybspark/input/PASSENGERS\.csv")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [PASSENGERID: int, PCLASS: int ... 9 more fields]

scala> val df3 = spark.read.option("header", true).option("inferSchema", false).schema(schema3).csv("s3a://mybucket/ybspark/input/PASSENGERS\.csv")
df3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [PASSENGERID: int, PCLASS: int ... 9 more fields]

scala> val df4 = spark.read.option("header", true).option("inferSchema", false).schema(schema4).csv("s3a://mybucket/ybspark/input/PASSENGERS\.csv")
df4: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [PASSENGERID: int, PCLASS: int ... 9 more fields]

scala> val df5 = spark.read.option("header", true).option("inferSchema", false).schema(schema5).csv("s3a://mybucket/ybspark/input/PASSENGERS\.csv")
df5: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [PASSENGERID: int, PCLASS: int ... 9 more fields]
```

Comment: isn't the inferSchema default false?  I actually just caught the order of the .schema.  Then had all nulls, although it was only one miscategorized field which seemed to call it (name) which made everything all nulls... in any case, fixed now.  Thanks!